# Does "to be on the rise" have any other meaning besides "to start", "to begin" and "to be getting momentum"?

Tags: meaning

Does "to be on the rise" have any other meaning besides "to start", "to begin" and "to be getting momentum"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A different shade of meaning than 'gaining momentum' would be improving, advancing or gaining in some desirable trait.  "My fortune is on the rise" -> my situation is improving.  "His star was on the rise" -> he was becoming more famous.
  I don't associate it with "starting" or "beginning", though.

Answer (score 3):

I never really thought of it as a metaphor for beginning - rather, it is simply a statement that your fortunes (or those of the subject) are improving.

Answer (score 0):

'to be on the rise' is a phrase for indicating progress, particularly in a way that catches attention and evokes admiration or jealousy or other emotions.